What's the correct way to invalidate image URL on Picasso?
My app uses Picasso 2.8, the latest.
There are a few parts that display profile pic, like this:
Picasso.get()
    .load(Constant.getInstance().MERCHANT.getProfPic())
    .resize(width, width)
    .centerInside()
    .placeholder(R.drawable.avatar)
    .error(R.drawable.avatar)
    .into(profPicView);

The problem is that the Constant.getInstance().MERCHANT.getProfPic() value is always the same, even if the actual content is changed, and Picasso caches the first URL, so it always displays the old profile pic. My idea is after the new profile picture is successfully uploaded, then clear the cache of that URL, like this:
             JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(
                        Request.Method.POST,
                        String.format("%s/v1/documents/cashierapp/%s", serverurl, Constant.getInstance().MERCHANT.getMobile()),
                        postData,
                        response -> {
                            Trace.i("ProfileImgHttpPostTask", response.toString());
                            Constant.getInstance().VolleyParams.remove("Authorization");
                            Constant.getInstance().VolleyParams.put("Authorization", Constant.getInstance().MERCHANT.getToken());

                            //invalidate old profile pic
                            Picasso.get().invalidate(Constant.getInstance().MERCHANT.getProfPic());

                            Picasso.get()
                                    .load(Constant.getInstance().MERCHANT.getProfPic())
                                    .resize(width, width)
                                    .centerInside()
                                    .placeholder(R.drawable.avatar)
                                    .error(R.drawable.avatar)
                                    .into(profPicView);


                        },
                        error -> {
                            Constant.getInstance().VolleyParams.remove("Authorization");
                            Constant.getInstance().VolleyParams.put("Authorization", Constant.getInstance().MERCHANT.getToken());
                            Trace.i("ProfileImgHttpPostTask", "HTTP " + error.networkResponse.statusCode + "\n" + new String(error.networkResponse.data, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                        }
                ) {
                    @Override
                    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {
                        Map<String, String> params = Constant.getInstance().VolleyParams;
                        params.put("appid", CashierApp.getInstance().appid);
                        params.put("Authorization", String.format("Bearer %s", CashierApp.getInstance().token));
                        return params;
                    }
                };
                jsonObjectRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                                30000,
                                1,
                                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT))
                        .setShouldCache(false)
                        .setShouldRetryServerErrors(false)
                        .setShouldRetryConnectionErrors(true);
                Constant.getInstance().getQueue().add(jsonObjectRequest);

It doesn't work as expected. Suddenly, the imageview displays the placeholder. Yet when I open Constant.getInstance().MERCHANT.getProfPic() on the browser, it displays the image recently uploaded. Which means Picasso still caches the old profile picture.
What's the proper way to do this? I've seen this post: Invalidate cache in Picasso. Before adding the invalidate() part, here's how I clear the cache:
Picasso.get()
    .load(Constant.getInstance().MERCHANT.getProfPic())
    .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE)
    .memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE)
    .resize(width, width)
    .centerInside()
    .placeholder(R.drawable.avatar)
    .error(R.drawable.avatar)
    .into(profPicView);

I also tried using stableKey() like this:
Picasso.get().invalidate(Constant.getInstance().MERCHANT.getProfPic());

Picasso.get()
    .load(Constant.getInstance().MERCHANT.getProfPic())
    .resize(width, width)
    .centerInside()
    .placeholder(R.drawable.avatar)
    .error(R.drawable.avatar)
    .stableKey(Constant.getInstance().MERCHANT.getProfPic())
    .into(profPicView);

Which doesn't work

This question is similar to: Invalidate cache in Picasso. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@AndrewT yes I've seen that post. Also I just updated my code based on of of the suggestions on that post. It doesn't work.
